# Zend Framework User Authentication

Tags: zend-framework, authentication

What is the best practice for user website/REST authentication in ZV MVC? How and **where to put the code** in the ZF framework? Can you provide me a code example?

I have a **website** and a **REST** server written in Zend Framework but no user session jet implemented.

THX!

Comment: Any luck with this? I am in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication is setup in the `_initAutoload` of the bootstrap file, e.g. like this:

```
if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
    Zend_Registry::set('role', Zend_Auth::getInstance()
                        ->getStorage()->read()->role);
}else{
    Zend_Registry::set('role', 'guests');
}
```

In case of a REST authentication you might need to authenticate by just passing the login parameters instead of logging in through a form.

So it might look like this in your `AuthenticationController`:

```
private function getAuthAdapter() {
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
                       Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter());
    $authAdapter->setTableName('users') // the db table where users are stored
                ->setIdentityColumn('email')                     
                ->setCredentialColumn('password')
                ->setCredentialTreatment('SHA1(CONCAT(?,salt))');

    return $authAdapter;
}

public function logoutAction() {
    Zend_Auth::getInstance()->clearIdentity();
    $this->_redirect('index/index');
}

public function loginAction(){
    if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()){
        $this->_redirect('index/index');
    }
    if ($request->isPost()){
        $username = $request->getPost('username');
        $password = $request->getPost('password');

        if ($username != "" && $password != "") {
            $authAdapter = $this->getAuthAdapter ();
            $authAdapter->setIdentity($username)
                        ->setCredential($password);
            $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

            if($result->isValid()){
              $identity = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject();
              $authStorage = $auth->getStorage();
              $authStorage->write($identity);
              $this->_redirect ( 'index/index' );
            } 
       }
   }
}
```

If you need more help on `zend_auth` and `zend_acl` you might have a look at this [how to](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmtGClgImpo).